Using formatter in expression binding in javascript xml view
I have an xml view where I am using the built in currency formatter to format the TotalNetAmount :
   <ObjectNumber id="idCurrencyStatus" 
                    number="{parts:[{path:'TotalNetAmount'},{path:'Currency'} ], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }"
                    unit="{Currency}"/>
                <ObjectIdentifier id="idLastChangeDateTime" text="{LastChangeDateTime}"/>    


I want to achieve the same in another xml view which has a conditional expression :
        <ObjectListItem id="itemObject" title="{PurchaseRequisitionItemText}" type="Navigation" numberUnit="{Currency}"
                        number="{= ${PurchasingDocumentItemCategory} === 'A' ? ${OverallLimitAmount} : ${TotalNetAmount}}
                        press=".onNavigate2Item">


How can I call the built in currency formatter in this case  ?
I tried to modify it as below-
        <ObjectListItem id="itemObject" title="{PurchaseRequisitionItemText}" type="Navigation" numberUnit="{Currency}"
                        number="{= ${PurchasingDocumentItemCategory} === 'A' ? ${OverallLimitAmount} : ${TotalNetAmount}, type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}}"
                        press=".onNavigate2Item">


But this gives a runtime error.
ANy help will be appreciated.
